# finding specific keywords in a list of documents with python

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, parameter-passing

**I get the following error when I try to run the code**

> `---> doc_list[index] = sentence.split()`
> **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'**

### word_search

*takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword.
Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents containing the keyword.*

### multi_word_search

*Takes list of documents (each document is a string) and a list of keywords.

Returns a dictionary where each key is a keyword, and the value is a list of indices
(from doc_list) of the documents containing that keyword*

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    keyword = keyword.lower()
    new_list = []
    for index, sentence in enumerate(doc_list):
        doc_list[index] = sentence.split()
        doc_list[index] = [word.lower().rstrip('.,') for word in doc_list[index]]
        for word in doc_list[index]:
            if word==keyword:
                new_list.append(index)
                break
    return new_list

def multi_word_search(doc_list, keywords):
    """
    Example:
    >>> doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car and a casino", 
    "Casinoville"]
    >>> keywords = ['casino', 'they']
    >>> multi_word_search(doc_list, keywords)
    {'casino': [0, 1], 'they': [1]}
    """
    result_dict = {keyword:word_search(doc_list,keyword) for keyword in keywords}
    return result_dict

doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car and a casino", 
"Casinoville"]
keywords = ['casino', 'they']
multi_word_search(doc_list, keywords)
```

Comment: `doc_list` is initially a list of strings. But your `word_search` function modifies it to become a list of lists. So the second call to `word_search` throws an exception, because it expects the elements of `doc_list` to be strings that can be split, but they are no longer strings, they're lists.

Comment: @slothrop you're absolutely right! If I run this code for a list of keywords that has only one element, let's say keywords=['casino']. this code works perfectly fine. but for second and other iterations it doesn't work. thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to split each sentence of the list, that way the code can be simplified:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    new_list = []
    for index, sentence in enumerate(doc_list):
        word = keyword.lower().rstrip('.,')
        if word in sentence.lower().rstrip('.,'):
            new_list.append(doc_list.index(sentence))
    return new_list

def multi_word_search(doc_list, keywords):
    dict = {}
    for word in keywords:
        value = word_search(doc_list, word)
        dict[word] = value
    return dict
```

Comment: FYI it's best to avoid using built-in names like `dict`; even `_dict` would be fine.

Comment: The reason to split each sentence is that OP seems to be trying to match on whole words. For example, if you don't split, then the keyword `hat` will match the sentence `I see that` - which is probably not what's required.

Comment: (Note the examples in the docstring of OP's 'multi_word_search'. They show that keyword `casino` should **not** match sentence `Casinoville`.)